# Verb meaning to solve problems through precision or accuracy?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am seeking an English verb meaning to solve or otherwise approach problems through some combination of precision, accuracy, flexibility, or even speed. There's plenty of relevant nouns, but I can't think of any corresponding verb forms.  By way of example, you can solve problems via strength if you **force** your way through, via intellect if you **reason** or **outwit**, or via social skills if you **charm**, **convince**, or **manipulate** others.

"Manipulate" almost gets at what I want, but I'd prefer something that points primarily to physical action and cannot be interpreted as a social action.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for the verb *finesse* ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finesse)):

> to bring about, direct, or manage by adroit maneuvering
>
> > finesse his way through tight places

Answer (score 1):

to **maneuver**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/maneuver)

> To act with skill or cunning in gaining an end:

As in:

*He maneuvered complexity, getting closer and closer to the X.*

When I think of **to maneuver**, stratagems, cunning and purpose of movement come to mind.